# Why SERIAL is not working on this simple table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm using Postgres 9.1. and the auto_increment (serial) is not working. I've just found this about 'serial':
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

```
CREATE TYPE FAMILY AS(
    id int,
    name VARCHAR(35),
    img_address VARCHAR(150));

CREATE TABLE FAMILIES of FAMILY(
    id SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
    name NOT NULL
    );

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SERIAL"
LINE 7:  id SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
                         ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SERIAL"
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: Why are you using the `TYPE` in the first place? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why not just use `create table families (id serial primary key, name varchar(35), img_address varchar(150));`?

Comment: Because I'm working with Java and I want create objects in the database.

Comment: That is totally unrelated on how you create the table in the database. And besides: if you just run `create table family (...)` you will automatically also have a type named `family`

Comment: No, if I create the table family, I have a table named family with its columns, nothing else. If I create a type (like in Java I create a class), I will have the table familiy with family objects inside, and it is more comfortable to me to work with, with the code I have.

Comment: Yes you have that table. **And** a type with that name (try it). You might think that your complicated way makes interfacing with Java easier. But in fact it will be more complicated in the long run, believe me. Stick to the simple solutions, don't over engineer things.

Comment: @tomyforever You must check your expectations about object orientation in relational databases. Hint: there is no OO.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried it and I have not a type by creating the table, for two reasons: types does not admit constraints. Creating the type after creating the table must give me an error for duplicated type and it doesn't. Any way your comment below the answer helped me.

Comment: Believe me: you do have both: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2869/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it works on postgre 9.3, I tried it in postgre 9.1 from pgadmin, and doest work.

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated version anyway? My example does work  on Postgres 9.1 - you just can't use named parameters in SQL functions there: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4515f/1  (And it's Postgres, not Postgre).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a table using the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx OF yyyy
```

you can add default values and constraints, but not alter or specify the type of the columns.

The type SERIAL is in effect a combination of a data type, NOT NULL constraint and default value specification. It is equivalent to:

```
integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
```

See: [documentation for SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

So, instead you would have to use:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE families_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE FAMILIES of FAMILY(
    id WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('families_id_seq'),
    name WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL
);

ALTER SEQUENCE families_id_seq OWNED BY FAMILIES.id;
```

You would have to create the sequence `families_id_seq` manually as well, as shown above.

Comment: Didn't get it. In the docs it sais: "The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns ". So 'serial' its just the word I should use for my sequence (which I  have to create)?

Comment: @user3502170: if you use `serial` with a "normal" table definition the sequence will automatically be created in the background. But as you are using the over-complicated setup with a type, you need to do that yourself.